# Perform a loop for a certain time interval or while condition is met

Tags: ruby, loops, time, ruby-1.9, ruby-2.0

I am trying to have a check fire off every second for 30 seconds. I haven't found a clear way to do this with Ruby yet. Trying something like this currently:

```
until counter == 30
  sleep 1
  if condition
    do something
    break
   else
     counter +=1
end
```

Problem with something like that is it has to use sleep, which stops the thread in its tracks for a full second. Is there another way to achieve something similar to the above without the use of sleep? Is there a way to have something cycle though on a time based interval?

Comment: Get rid of the counter variable and use either `for i in 1..30` or `1.upto(30)` or `(1..30).each`.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with the thread while you wait?  You might want to check out something like [IO#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-select) if you're trying to check for IO and do something else if it's not there.  It's unclear from your code above whether there's any other processing to do.  There's nothing inherently wrong with just sleeping.

Comment: Sorry for being vague in question. I am running an event based bot that is event driven / multi threaded. I was wanting to check if a condition occurs within a 30 sec window of the event that triggered the loop. I was wanting to do the check fairly often(1 sec or os intervals) within that 30 seconds. The condition is updated / occurs within another event and I want this loop to check  and perform a reaction based on that condition arising / not arising.

Comment: SLeep was causing some delay / inability to trigger the event this loop was in. The event itself has numerous conditionals that lead to differing responses, which is why I didnt want to use the slleep route.

Answer (score 4):

You can approximate what you're looking for with something along these lines:

```
now = Time.now
counter = 1
loop do
  if Time.now < now + counter
    next
  else
    puts "counting another second ..."
  end
  counter += 1
  break if counter > 30
end
```

Comment: I think this actually accomplished what I was setting out to do, I wasn't aware that adding an integer value to a time was the equivalent of ading seconds to the time. Thanks

Comment: This is worse than sleeping though as it will pin your CPU.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something simple like..

```
max_runtime = 10.seconds.from_now
puts 'whatever' until Time.now > max_runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this it allows for interval controls

```
counter == 30
interval = 5 # Check every 5 seconds
interval_timer = 1 # must start at 1
now = Time.now
while Time.now - now < counter
    if interval_timer % interval == 0 #Every 5 attempts the activity will process
        if condition
            stuff
        end
    end
    process_timer = process_timer + 1
end
```

This will happen under a guaranteed 30 seconds the interval can be set to any value 1 or greater. Some things process via milliseconds this will give you an option that will save you cycles on processing. Works well in graphics processing.